# Responsive Design - Toggle a Div's Visibility - how to integrate javascript with css @media

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I started a previous thread with the same goal but now I have the real question and have created two fiddles [jsfiddle #1](https://jsfiddle.net/mseifert/m9pk3m7r/) AND jsfiddles [jsfiddle #2](https://jsfiddle.net/mseifert/t035rgs1/2/) to show the problem.

I am attempting to use principles of responsive design to adapt to changing screen size. It has these two parts

- Use CSS to hide/show a vertical menu div (`main-nav-vert`) using `@media` based on browser width.
- Use a Menu button to also hide/show the same div `main-nav-vert` using javascript.

The problem I am having is that I can find a way to integrate the javascript with the `@media` rules. I am open to another way (but without jQuery)

**The Problem:**
To test these fiddles and see the problem: Reduce the window size to see the impact of `@media` and it should hide the menu on the left. Expand the window and the menu should reappear. Now shrink the window again until the menu disappears. Click the button and the menu appears. Click the button a second time to hide it. NOW, expanding the window will no longer show the menu.

**Try #1**
([jsfiddle #1](https://jsfiddle.net/mseifert/m9pk3m7r/))

- javascript changes the same `display` property of `main-nav-vert` that `@media` is changing.
- javascript only changes the element NOT the underlying CSS (as shown in the inspector).
- The element values set by javascript will take precedence over the CSS property set by `@media` and so ...
- once the button is pressed, the `@media` settings will no longer work - being overridden.

**Try #2**
([jsfiddle #2](https://jsfiddle.net/mseifert/t035rgs1/2/))

- javascript alternately sets a new class to the `main-nav-vert` div (`hidden` and `visible`) with each click of the button.
- the `display` property for `main-nav-vert` set by `@media` will take precedence over the `display` property from the `hidden` class and the button will not hide the menu ... UNLESS
- I override the `display` property by using `!important` in the `visible` and `hidden` classes, but then `@media` won't work as before.

Please help. There must be a better way. I am looking for a pure js answer, please no jQuery. Thanks.

Comment: Checkout enquire.js http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/

Comment: @KevinBoucher - thanks for the link. It looks very promising. If no one has a solution, I will download the library and give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer with `window.matchMedia` and `addlistener`. Basically, I added a javascript listener for a media query. The javascript fires whenever the condition (screen size) crosses the boundary.

I have posted [the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mseifert/hrc9vcjs/) with a working solution.

**html**

```
<div class="page-container">
    <div class="div-menu-toggle" id="div-menu-toggle">
    <button type="button" onClick="showmenu();">Menu</button>
    </div>
    <div class="main-nav-vert visible" id="main-nav-vert">
    <ul class="nav-vert">
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="main-content" id="main-content">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
    </div>
    </div>
```

**css**

```
.main-nav-vert{
    display: block;
    float:left; 
    width:145px;
    border:solid 2px #00f;
}

.div-menu-toggle{
    display: none;
}

.main-content{
    max-width:808px; 
    width: auto;
    padding:0 9px 0 9px;
    margin-left: 145px;
}
```

**javascript**

```
var jmq = window.matchMedia( "(max-width: 480px)" )
var keepOpen = false;

jmq.addListener(jmqListener);
window.onload = function() {
jmqListener(jmq);
};   

function jmqListener(jmq){
var button = document.getElementById('div-menu-toggle');
var menu = document.getElementById('main-nav-vert');
var content = document.getElementById('main-content');
if (jmq.matches) {
    // window width is less than 480px
    //show menu button
    button.style.display = "block";
    if (keepOpen == false){
    // if keepOpen flag is not set, hide the menu
    menu.style.display = "none";
    // set left margin of main-content to fill screen
    content.style.marginLeft = "2px";
    }       
}
else {
    // window width is at least 480px
    //hide menu button
    button.style.display = "none";
    // if show the menu
    menu.style.display = "block";
    // set left margin of main-content to make room
    content.style.marginLeft = "145px";
}    
}

function showmenu() {
var menu = document.getElementById('main-nav-vert');
var content = document.getElementById('main-content');
// with click on menu button
if(menu.style.display == "block"){
    // if menu is already open, hide it
    menu.style.display = "none";
    keepOpen = false;
    // set left margin of main-content to fill screen
    content.style.marginLeft = "2px";
}
else {
    // menu is closed - show the menu
    menu.style.display = "block";
    // set a flag that it is open
    keepOpen = true;
    // set left margin of main-content to make room
    content.style.marginLeft = "145px";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need? I am having a hard time understanding what it is you want the links to do here are my two different solutions.

css

```
.main-content {
    max-width:808px; 
    width: auto;
    padding:0 9px 0 9px;
}
.main-nav-vert {
    display: block;
    float:left; 
    width:145px;
    border:solid 2px #00f;
}

.visible{
    display: block !important;
}

.hidden{
    display: none !important;
}

@media (min-width: 450px) {
       #main-nav-vert{
           display: block;
       }
    }
@media (max-width: 449px){
       #main-nav-vert{
           display: none;
       }
        .hidden{
            display: none;
            }
    }
```

css

```
.main-content {
    max-width:808px; 
    width: auto;
    padding:0 9px 0 9px;
}
.main-nav-vert {
    display: block;
    float:left; 
    width:145px;
    border:solid 2px #00f;
}

.visible{
    display: block !important;
}

.hidden{
    display: none !important;
}

@media (min-width: 450px) {
       #main-nav-vert{
           display: block;
       }
    }
@media (max-width: 449px){
       #main-nav-vert{

           display: none !important;
       }
    }

#main-nav-vert{
     display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. CSS changes alone didn't allow for both the button and the @media to be changing the same live properties. It required a javascript only solution - which I posted above.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to use window resize event, check your breakpoints and set condition to show/hide

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    if(window.innerWidth > 768)
    {
        // hide menubar
    }else{
       // show menubar
    }
};
```

Comment: It looks like that may work as an alternative to `window.matchMedia`. However, `matchMedia` only fires when the media query changes between true and false. It looks like `onresize` will fire more often and therefore take more processing - but probably minimal. I will experiment to see. One advantage is better browser support for older browsers. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: After some research, the following is indicative of [what I've read](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-media-queries/): "Detecting screen dimension changes is also possible with window.onresize. However, older versions of IE continually fire this event as the window is altered — it can crash the browser.

Even if you successfully detect viewport dimension changes, you must calculate factors such as orientation and aspect ratios yourself. There’s no guarantee it’ll match your browser’s assumptions when it applies media query rules in CSS." - I'll stick with `matchMedia`. I appreciate it.